# Is there an equivalent to the `any` method in python

Tags: rust, any, syntactic-sugar

There is a very convenient function called [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) in the standard library of Python, that allows to check given if any item in a given iterable verifies some condition.

```py
my_list = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8]

# using any
four_is_present = any(elem == 4 for elem in my_list)

# is equivalent to
four_is_present = False
for elem in my_list:
    if elem == 4:
        four_is_present = True
        break
```

I am wondering if there is an equivalent syntactic sugar in Rust, or if I have to go for the "longer" expression.

Comment: The "longer" expression is shorter in Rust... https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7afc4b8fc7505c413b472c519a495047 What is your actual question?

Comment: What do you mean by "longer"? Please specify it (e.g. by a link to the doc or by code)

Comment: If you are working with a `Vec`/`slice` anyway, you can use [`contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.contains) which [uses any under the hood](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.34.0/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#5160)

Comment: My question was answered by @French .... I'm still a newbie in rust, so I did not think straight about using clojure, nor did I know about `any`. So thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @m.raynal 3rd result: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=any

Comment: @French, sorry, I ended up on the [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) page when searching, so I came up here to ask ... should have searched longer, my bad. But still, I would not have come up with a clojure, there's a bunch of new reflexes to acquire when learning rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. There is [`Iterator::any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) which is a method on an Iterator (in contrast to Python where it is a free-standing function which accepts an Iterator).

You can call it like any other method.

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_list = vec![1, 3, 4, 5, 8];
    println!("{}", my_list.iter().any(|&i| i == 4));
}
```

---

If you are using a `Vec` or a `slice` anyway, you can use [`contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.contains) which will use the `any` method in [its implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.34.0/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#5160).

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_list = vec![1, 3, 4, 5, 8];
    println!("{}", my_list.contains(&4));
}
```

The [API doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) will also list other useful methods, e.g. `all`, `chain`, `zip`, `map` or `filter`. Also there are examples to those methods in the documentation which are all worth reading.